# SimpleXML display value of specific attribute

Tags: php, simplexml

I have simple XML element called $element but I can't manage to get specific result. For example I want value of specific attribute.

For example I need value for attribute named "Product" so expected result is "XYZ top".

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [attribute] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Product
                        )
                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Price
                        )
                )
            )
 [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => XYZ top
            [1] => 999.25
        )
)
```

Did not manage to find solution elsewhere. Tried this and many other things:

```
echo $element->attributes()->{'Product'};

foreach($element->specification as $dat) {
    foreach ($dat->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        echo $a,'="',$b,'"';
    if ($b=='Product') {
    echo "right one";
            }
}
echo " -> ".$dat."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Have you done any searching on how to solve this and made any attempt?

Comment: @PatrickQ yes. Now edited question.

Comment: @Jeto no, it is different. Here is entire content of $element.

Comment: @Ivan First, that seems to be a very oddly-constructed XML file.  Are you able to change how it is created?  Second, if not, is it always the cast that the product name is in the first position and price in the second?

Comment: @PatrickQ Not always. Sometimes first field does not even exist.
Here is screenshot of actual XML http://prntscr.com/mat4zn

Comment: So back to my first question, are you able to change the construction of the XML file?

Comment: @PatrickQ unfortunately no. I can not edit it.